# How to give multiple SourceArn for AWS::Lambda::Permission in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation

I have updated the template.yaml file as below, I need to give permission to multiple schedulers for an lambda function.

```
  ## Grant permission to Events trigger Lambda
  PermissionForEventsToInvokeSchedulerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref SchedulerFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: 
        - !GetAtt AsyncDashboardFirstDayMonthScheduledRule.Arn
        - !GetAtt AsyncDashboardOnceEveryDayScheduledRule.Arn
        - !GetAtt AsyncDashboardOnceEveryOnehourScheduledRule.Arn
```

Getting error below.

```
Value of property SourceArn must be of type String
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check aws docs's [SourceArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-sourcearn) you will see that this is a **string**, not a list of strings. So you can have only one value in `SourceArn`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple Lambda Permission. sample:

```html
PermissionForEventsMonthly:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref SchedulerFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt AsyncDashboardFirstDayMonthScheduledRule.Arn
PermissionForEventsDaily:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref SchedulerFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt AsyncDashboardOnceEveryDayScheduledRule.Arn
```